# onRequestPermissionsResult is not called in fragment android

Tags: android, android-fragments

i am taking runtime permission from user by using below code in fragment .

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity,
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                        STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);


                            }
```

and overriding

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 21: {

                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.




                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }
```

but override method not called

please give me hint for that i have to override in fragment

Comment: yes it is 21 @user13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Becouse remember for futher u must do this in ACTIVITY not in a fragment. Yoou can d this tricky in fragment but this is bad way

this is in Activity. I check permissions and save it

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_GET_ACCOUNTS = 101;
    private static final int REQUEST_AUDIO_PERMISSION = 102;

 @TargetApi(23)
public void checkAudioPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        playerFragment.setupVisualizerFxAndUI();
        return;
    }
    if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager
            .PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                REQUEST_AUDIO_PERMISSION);
    } else {
        playerFragment.setupVisualizerFxAndUI();
    }
}

@TargetApi(23)
public void checkGmailPermission() {
    if (isDeviceOnline()) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            showGmailRecFragment(true);
            return;
        }
        if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS) != PackageManager
                .PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS},
                    REQUEST_CODE_GET_ACCOUNTS);
            return;
        } else {
            showGmailRecFragment(true);
        }
    } else {
        Utils.showToast(this, getString(R.string.no_internet));
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[]
        grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_GET_ACCOUNTS:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                showGmailRecFragment(true);
            } else {
                Utils.showToast(this, getString(R.string.accounts_permision_denied));
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_AUDIO_PERMISSION:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                playerFragment.setupVisualizerFxAndUI();
            } else {
                Utils.showToast(this, getString(R.string.audio_permission_denied));
            }
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            break;
    }
}
```

and this is on fragment when i want check permission again or if user denied it. Also this save the permissions

```
private void setupViewVisualizer() {
    if (!isLiveTv && !homeVideo.isVideoType()) {
        ((PlayerActivity) activity).checkAudioPermission();
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes , but how can i call process after granting permission like  camera should open after getting permission in activity

while my code of open camera in fragment

Comment: Yea u can save permissions on activity but if user decline this u can call method in fragment like ((MainActivity)context).checkPermissions();

Remember that checking, saving permissions on Activities is good practice

Answer (score 1):

Use `FragmentCompat` instead of `ActivityCompat`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for Fragment

```
 private void requestReadExternalStorageCameraPermission() {
    if (FragmentCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
        Toast.show(getActivity(), getString(R.string.toast_permission), Toast.ToastType.ALERT);
    } else {
        FragmentCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA);
    }
}
```

and

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[],
                                       int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE_GALLARY:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                captureImageInitialization(1);
            }
            break;
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[2] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                captureImageInitialization(0);
            }


            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: which fragment you are using?

Comment: android.support.v4.app.Fragment @jinal patel

Comment: you need to add this in your gradle file
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.4.0'

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
 private static final int REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION = 123;

if (CheckPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
// you have permission go ahead

} else {
// you do not have permission go request runtime permissions
RequestPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION);
}


  @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int permsRequestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

        switch (permsRequestCode) {

            case REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                } else {
                    // you do not have permission show toast.
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    public void RequestPermission(Activity thisActivity, String Permission, int Code) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Permission)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
                    Permission)) {

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                        new String[]{Permission},
                        Code);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean CheckPermission(Activity context, String Permission) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue,

It is a common mistake and it is very simple to solve.

if you are in an activity we normally use 
`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, permissionsNeeded.toTypedArray(),PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)`

But you shouldn't use the same for a fragment. You can simply use it like `requestPermissions(permissionsNeeded.toTypedArray(),PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)`

If you call the Activity.requestPermission in fragment, the on request callback is get called in the Activity not in the Fragment.

Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

### when Request for Permission from fragment

- Kotlin

  `requireActivity().requestPermissions(<Permission array>, <Request code>)`
- Java

  `getActivity().requestPermissions(<Permission array>, <Request code>)`

#### You can call fragment onRequestPermissionsResult from activity's onRequestPermissionsResult

- Kotlin

```
        var fragments:List? = supportFragmentManager.fragments
        var lastFragment:Fragment? = if(fragments!=null && fragments.size>0) fragments.get(fragments.size-1) else null
        var lastFragmentName:String? = if(lastFragment!=null) lastFragment.javaClass.name else ""
    
        if (lastFragmentName.equals("com.example.YourFragment")){
            lastFragment?.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResults)
        }
```

- Java

```
        List fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
        Fragment lastFragment = (fragments!=null && fragments.size()>0)?fragments.get(fragments.size()-1) : null;
        String lastFragmentName = (lastFragment!=null) ? lastFragment.getClass().getName() : "";

        if (lastFragment!=null && lastFragmentName.equals("com.example.YourFragment")){
            lastFragment.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResults);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle permissions in a `Fragment` call `requestPermissions` method. If you override `onRequestPermissionsResult` method in both fragment and activity, containing that fragment, make sure to call `super.onRequestPermissionsResult(...)` in the activity method to propagate call to the `onRequestPermissionsResult` method in the fragment.